# how to unzip a file in lua on nginx server?

Tags: nginx, lua, unzip, lua-table, nginx-location

I am trying to find a zip/unzip module in lua that can be use on the nginx server.

My use case is, when calling an nginx server api, i need to get the zip file from the request body and read each file at a time and store it in some where.

Which lua module can help in achieving it in the nginx server.

Tried lua-zip module,  but not working till now.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried?

Comment: I know that using Lua with C module compatibility you can use lzlib or lua-zlib.

Comment: trying to use https://github.com/brimworks/lua-zip it gives me error while loading the zip.so module -- error is undefined symbol: zip_get_error  i have installed cmake and the libzib library as mentioned in the git gub page......         particulary this line -   zip = require("brimworks.zip") gives error: error loading module 'brimworks.zip' from file '/usr/code/modules/lua-zip/build/brimworks/zip.so':
 /usr/code/modules/lua-zip/build/brimworks/zip.so: undefined symbol: zip_get_error
stack traceback:

Comment: sorry,                                                                                                            when i run the script directly the require('zip') is able to load the library but when i try to run the cript through a nginx api                                                                                       ------                modules/lua-zip/build/brimworks/zip.so':
 /usr/code/modules/lua-zip/build/brimworks/zip.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_zip

Comment: If you are running your ngx api through openresty then you will need to copy the zlib.so file into /usr/local/openresty/lualib/ or wherever your lualib directory is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gunzip on` and `gzip on`  in your server or http directives.